# Why is NSIS check for JRE broken?

Tags: nsis

Why does this script try to install the jre when it doesn't need to? I verified that `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe` does in fact exist, but this script doesn't see it. The script is targeting XP, Vista, 32 bit, and 64 bit. The script !includes `x64.nsh`. The reason for the first ElseIf is that the javaw.exe is sometimes installed in `C:\Windows\System32\` on 64 bit systems. Is the logic bogus? If so, how? Is the use of `C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe` improper?

```
${If} ${FileExists} `$SYSDIR\javaw.exe`
    ; Skip JRE install
${ElseIf} ${FileExists} `C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe`
    ; Skip JRE install
${ElseIf} ${RunningX64}
    ExecWait '"jre-6u22-windows-x64.exe"'
${Else}
    ExecWait '"jre-6u22-windows-i586-s.exe"'
${EndIf}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed Unless blocks and DisableX64FSRedirection.

```
${If} ${RunningX64} 
    ${DisableX64FSRedirection} 
    ${Unless} ${FileExists} "$SYSDIR\javaw.exe" 
        ExecWait '"jre-6u22-windows-x64.exe"'
    ${EndUnless} 
    ${EnableX64FSRedirection} 
${Else}  
    ${Unless} ${FileExists} "$SYSDIR\javaw.exe" 
        ExecWait '"jre-6u22-windows-i586-s.exe"'
    ${EndUnless} 
${EndIf}
```